# How to I align a GIS map (using Netlogo extension) with a database of city lat/long data?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I want to map cities on the U.S. or a particular state.  I have a data set with the lat/long for each city.  I was using a data set of boundary points for the U.S., as well as individual states.  I am switching to a map of the U.S. usig the NETLOGO GIS extension.  The cities no longer line up.  The GIS map seems to fill the "world view", but it is slightly distorted from the U.S. map built from 80000 individual points (instead of Vector map).  How can I make sure the GIS map is line up with the right lat/long?

Comment: This tutorial on the GIS extension may help https://simulatingcomplexity.wordpress.com/author/benjdavies/page/3/